# How do browser get the required font file?

Tags: browser, fonts, font-face, truetype, webfonts

I was searching through the net and couldn't find the exact answer.

How do browsers get the exact .ttf file for a font family specified in the css? Does it already have it in its code or does it pick from the user's system. I guess we can always specify the custom font files using the @font-face but what about the normal general fonts like arial etc?

Answer (score 0):

The process is obviously different between browsers and operating systems, but in short, browsers pick the font from the system, and if it’s not installed, the font will be replaced with another similar font.